# После завершения процесса библиотека остается занятой

Tags: c#

Сразу скажу, предоставить код я не смогу. Да и вряд ли бы это помогло. Поэтому жду теоретических предположений либо методику выявления проблемы.

Итак, есть солюшн. В проблеме участвуют 3 проекта:

- Клиент - компилируется в *client.exe*
- Стартер - компилируется в *starter.exe*
- Конфиг - компилируется в *config.dll*

Я запускаю *client.exe*. При запуске без параметров он запускает процесс *starter.exe* и сам завершается. В стартере открывается форма с выбором сервера и двумя кнопочками: "Настройки" и "Подключиьтся". Когда я жму Подключиться, происходит подключение к выбранному серверу, с которого сначала получаются обновленные файлы (в тч *client.exe* и *config.dll*), затем запускается *client.exe* и стартер вырубается. Так должно быть. **НО**...

Обновление не проходит. При обновлении он не может заменить библиотеку *config.dll*, потому что она занята. Проверяю *процесс эксплоером*. А занята она оказывается процессом *starter.exe*! Почему? У него нет в референсах ни клиента ни конфига, так что он не должен ее цеплять. Это какая то магия, помогите!

**UPD:**

Выяснил, что занята еще одна библиотека - *ResourceLibrary.dll*. Их связывает одно - картиночки, которые в них содержатся. Я сменил действие при сборке, установил *Resource*. Раньше эти библиотеки заняты не были.

Вопрос. Может ли один процесс подхватывать ресурсы другого? Зачем он это делает и как это предотвратить?

Comment: 1. А Вы **абсолютно** уверены, что у `starter` нет зависимостей на `config`?
2. Как запускается `starter`?

Comment: @kff, я был уверен в этом.... до недавнего времени :)  Короче ссылка была в XAMLe стартера. Там формочка ссылалась на файл стилей из Конфига, причем в референсах стартера конфига нет. Ссылка была подчеркнута в дизайнере, но во время выполнения она оказывалась вполне таки рабочей. Но откуда мне было знать о ее существовании? Сложно отследить такие вот ссылки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помогли мне тут

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/f10b1709-8cdd-46bf-9ffa-5395257a7265/-?forum=fordesktopru

Вот методика для моего случая (можно легко использовать для вашего)

1. Проверьте, нет ли у вас из Starter референсов на другие проекты, которые использую конфиг.
2. Прямо поиском поищите в стартере Load, может вы не правы насчет рефлекшена?
3. Сбилдите проект, удалите руками Config и запустите стартер из студии, посмотрите где упадет.

А проблема была в следующем:

В стартере в новой WPF формочке был подключен ResourceDictionary из конфига. Строка была подчеркнута, типа он не знает где искать данный файл, потому что конфига не было в референсах, но тем не менее во время выполнения он его находил. Короче дело было не в бабине.

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ как верный (через пару дней кнопка станет доступна).